# wpf menuitem - ischeckable with children

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, menu, menuitem

Im building a context menu, and noticed that when my top list of menuitems have ischeckable turned on, they wont show any child menu items. but what I'd like to do is be able to:

-navigate to a child item, pick it, and have it propagate to the top menu

-next time i want to use this item, i can just click it on the top level menu and it will be selected, without necessarily needing to drill into the children to reselect it.

Appreciate any pointers on how to have the top menu be checkable and still allow children menus items.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112880/checkable-menuitem-with-sub-menus